# how to handle new lines in Regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I have an application that reads codes from a text file written in C#.

The codes will generally follow the same pattern each time

**example**:

> QUES10100

From what i have written so far this results in the regular expression looking like this:

```
string expr = "^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{5}$";
```

The question then is when the codes are read from a text file ( One per new line ) the codes have the `\r` new line character appended. This is from placing a breakpoint on to see what was really being passed through.

What am i missing from the expression provided above?

Also if i am adding the codes individually the /r characters are not appended so its fine, in this case i would need an or operand in there somewhere.

**Summary**

What I have so far: `^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{5}$`

What I need: `^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{5}$` **OR** `^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{5}$` with /r characters accounted for.

---

> Thanks, any clarifications please let me know as my experience with
>   REGEX is very limited.

---

**Update**

```
string expr = "^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{5}";

Regex regex = new Regex(expr , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = regex.Match( code );

if (!match.Success) //Pattern must match
{
  MessageBox.Show("Code does not match the necessary pattern");
  return false;
}

 return true;
```

Comment: why not use C# string.Split method and you can split on multiple delimiters.. just curious also you need to check for not only `\r but \n also`

Comment: @MethodMan I wasnt aware i could do that in c# I need to Google how that works. For the mean time the expression provided does about 50% of the work intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no control over how are the strings being read, you could also take a look at the [`String.Trim(char\[\] values)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which would allow you to sanitize your string before hand:

Something like the below:

```
string str = "....".Trim(new char[] {'\r', '\n'});
```

This is usually recommended (since almost anything is better than regex :)).

Then you would feed it to the regular expression you have built.

Comment: Whats going on in the code here? does it just remove the "\r" and "\n" values from the string?

Comment: @KyleT: It removes them *if and only if* they are at the start **and** end of the string. If you want to remove only from the front, you can take a look at the `String.TrimStart()`

Comment: Answer accepted because it provides the ability to test using either a text file with /r appended to the string or the code string without.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use regex for that? Use `File.ReadLines` and use the regex for validation.

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(@"c:\file path here")) {
    if (Regex.Test(expr, line)) {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Updating the question, for reference I used the Regex and Match objects to solve part of the question.